# Exited with code 139 (Segmentation fault)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The program compiles properly, but when I try to input any number, it terminates with error code 139.
The problem is probably on the second for loop, because I commented out the entire clause and everything works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int t;
  scanf("%d", &t);
  int a[t], b[t];
  for(int i=0; i<t; i++)
  {
    scanf("%d%d", &a[i], &b[i]);
  }

  for(int i=0; i<t; i++)
  {
    int min = 0;
    while(a[i]!=b[i])
    {
      if(a[i]<b[i])
      {
        for(int j=a[i]; j<b[i]; j+=10)
        {
          if(b[i]-j>10)
          {
            min += 1;
            a[i] += j;
          } else
          {
            min += 1;
            a[i] = b[i];
          }
        }
      } else
      {
        for(int j=b[i]; j>a[i]; j-=10)
        {
          if(j-a[i]>10)
          {
            min += 1;
            a[i] -= j;
          } else
          {
            min += 1;
            a[i] = b[i];
          }
        }
      }
    }
    printf("%d\n", min);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I also want to note, that each other compilation of the program shows "Segmentation fault (core dump)" or just "Segmentation fault", which is weird. There are also times that it doesn't show any errors, but still doesn't accept input regardless.

Edit: Now when I enter a third input for a[i] and b[i], the program freezes.

Comment: You never change a[i] or b[i] inside the while loop, so t should run forever or not at all.

Comment: What value is `t`?

Comment: @WeatherVane It is set by scanf.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Make sure you are running the program you think you are running. I recommend copying the program and the input data over to one of the online compiler sites and trying it there.

Comment: There is no `scanf` inside the *while* loop.

Comment: What ***value*** is t? It is entered with `scanf()`. What was the return value from `scanf()`? It should be `1`.

Comment: BTW, what is this program supposed to do?

Comment: OT: regarding: `#include <stdlib.h>`  it is a poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used.  Suggest removing that statement.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding (the compiler does not care)  1) Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) Please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: (the compiler does not care)  insert a (reasonable) space: inside parens, inside braces, inside brackets, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing `a[i]` nor `b[i]` inside the `while` loop. Supposing you want to exit once it checks all of the array's position, you should introduce this condition (changed it to a for, much easier):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int t;
  scanf("%d", &t);
  int a[t], b[t];
  for(int i=0; i<t; i++)
  {
    scanf("%d%d", &a[i], &b[i]);
  }

  for(int i=0; i<t; i++)
  {
    int min = 0;
    for(;a[i]!=b[i] && i<t;i++) //Here
    {
      if(a[i]<b[i])
      {
        for(int j=a[i]; j<b[i]; j+=10)
        {
          if(b[i]-j>10)
          {
            min += 1;
          }
        }
      } else
      {
        for(int j=b[i]; j>a[i]; j-=10)
        {
          if(j-a[i]>10)
          {
            min += 1;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    printf("%d\n", min);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Alright, changed it. I also tried changing the a[i] and b[i] values inside the former while loop. There is no segmentation fault anymore, but entering the third value for the arrays, the program freezes.